# Get pixel width of d3.js SVG element after it's created with width as percentage

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I want to place a svg bar chart into a certain div and fail to get the calculated svg width if I set the attribute "width" as a percentage. I would like to stick to giving the size as a percentage to be able to calculate bar widths etc. from the svg size.

The div for the chart:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

The code for appending the SVG, place in a function before that. The function is called to put data in a bootrap modal:

```
var prodChart = d3.select("#chart");
var w = "100%";
var h = "100%";

// remove existing svg in div
prodChart.select("svg").remove();

var chartSVG = prodChart.append("svg")
              .attr(":xmlns:svg", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
              .attr("id","prodchartsvg")
              .style("width", w)
              .style("height", h)
              .attr("class", "thumbnail");
```

To **get the calculated size in pixels**, I already tried this:

```
$("#prodchartsvg").width();                                // not working, returns 100
$("#chart").width();                                       // not working, returns null
prodchartsvg.node().getBBox();                             // prodchartsvg.node is not a  function
d3.select("#prodchartsvg").style("width");                 // returns 100%
chartSVG.style("width");                                   // returns auto
d3.select("#prodchartsvg").node().getBoundingClientRect(); // returns 0 for all parameters
d3.select("#chart").node().getBoundingClientRect();        // returns 0 for all parameters
```

I realise some of the above functions I tried are unsuitable in this context (DOM, object, ...).

Can you give me an idea how to get the svg width in **pixels instead of a percentage**?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: I put this code: `var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("id", "asvg").attr("width", "100%").attr("height", "100%");` and `alert($("#asvg").width());` into a Fiddle and it appears to be working in both Firefox and Chrome. Perhaps there is something else going wrong? Returns the same numbers whether height/width are set with `attr` or `style`. Does it return anything different for you if you set dimensions using `.attr`?

Comment: Thank you for trying! That's odd, running your code outputs the correct value. But as soon as i put `d3.select("#someID")`, instead of `d3.select("body")` the output is "100" in my Firefox console, which I suspect to be 100%... The svg seems to be about 280px wide (if i check by inserting e.g. a filled rectangle). Using `.attr` and `.style` made no difference.

Comment: That is very strange. Even when I put a `div` with `id` of `chart` into the HTML it still works fine. You're probably right about the 100 being a percentage. Perhaps it doesn't calculate this in real-time because it has a parent? Does it return anything different when you try to get the width of `svg[0].parentNode`? It returns a slightly larger value for me (720 versus 704), but I suppose it would be better than nothing if it works.

Comment: Very likely your div is hidden at the time you're trying to calculate the width. The div must be visible in the DOM in order to calculate the width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @nrabinowitz commented, your problem is most probably caused by the fact that your SVG is not visible in the screen at the moment when you attempt to retrieve its width.

### Test case

In the following snippet, we compare the value returned by `$("#prodchartsvg").width()` for two svgs, one hidden and one displayed.

```js
var prodChart = d3.select("#chart");
var w = "100%";
var h = "100%";

// remove existing svg in div
prodChart.select("svg").remove();

var hiddenSVG = prodChart.append("svg")
              .attr(":xmlns:svg", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
              .attr("id","hiddenSVG")
              .style('display', 'none') // not shown on screen
              .style("width", w)
              .style("height", h)
              .attr("class", "thumbnail");

$('#result').html('hiddenSVG width is ' + $("#hiddenSVG").width())


var shownSVG = prodChart.append("svg")
              .attr(":xmlns:svg", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
              .attr("id","shownSVG")
              .style("width", w)
              .style("height", h)
              .attr("class", "thumbnail");

$('#result').append('<br>shownSVG width is ' + $("#shownSVG").width())
```

```css
svg {background-color: #eee}
```

```html
<div id='chart'></div>
<div id='result'></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### How to fix

Try one of these solutions:

1. make sure the chart is displayed on screen whenever you compute the width
2. make sure the DOM is loaded whenever you compute the width. Either move you script at the end of the html `body`, or wrap your code inside a jQuery DOM ready function...